# Get Array in foreach loop from string

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach, strpos

I have an Array of Strings, each String that exist in Advanced Custom Fields groups should be returned in foreach loop. Final results should be a single array of all values.

```
$lubuvna_groups = acf_get_field_groups();

$ArrayDiffs = array_diff($resultsFilesKey, $resultsKey);

foreach($ArrayDiffs as $ArrayDiff) { 
   $resultsFileToImports[] = $ArrayDiff;
}

//$keysToImports = implode(", ",$resultsFileToImports);
$keysToImports = 'group_lubuvna_contact, group_lubuvna_subscriber';
    foreach($resultsFileToImports as $resultsFileToImportsKey) { 
        $keysToImports_filtered = array_filter($lubuvna_groups, function($el) use ($keysToImports) {
                        
            return ( strpos($el['key'], $keysToImports) !== false );

        });
}
```

The above code returns only if one string exists in $keysToImports. Once there are more than one value it doesn't work. I am sure i am missing something, but can't find any solution in here!
It shows me empty Array:

```
Array ( )
```

Maybe there is a different way how to get the arrays without strpos?

Final Array should looks like following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 0 [key] => group_lubuvna_contact [title] => ACF Fields [fields] => Array ( ) [location] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [param] => post_type [operator] => == [value] => page ) ) ) [menu_order] => 0 [position] => normal [style] => default [label_placement] => top [instruction_placement] => label [hide_on_screen] => [active] => 1 [description] => [local] => json [modified] => 1592781382 [_valid] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 0 [key] => group_lubuvna_subscriber [title] => Lubuvna - Subscriber Fields [fields] => Array ( ) [location] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [param] => post_type [operator] => == [value] => post ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [param] => post_type [operator] => == [value] => page ) ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [param] => post_type [operator] => == [value] => lubuvna_subscriber ) ) ) [menu_order] => 0 [position] => normal [style] => default [label_placement] => top [instruction_placement] => label [hide_on_screen] => [active] => 1 [description] => [local] => json [modified] => 1592781369 [_valid] => 1 ) )
```

Comment: The code seems to have various values which seem to have no purpose (or not in the code).  `$ArrayDiffs` is put into `$resultsFileToImports`, you then `foreach` over this list into `$resultsFileToImportsKey` which is not used anywhere.

Comment: @NigelRen I had two arrays which at the end used in `$ArrayDiffs` , i have added it this to code above. this is what i get from `. $ArrayDiffs `.  `. Array ( [0] => group_lubuvna_contact [1] => group_lubuvna_subscriber ) `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
$keysToImports = 'group_lubuvna_contact', 'group_lubuvna_subscriber';
// then return
return ( strpos($el['key'], $keysToImports) !== false );
```

to

```
$keysToImports = ['group_lubuvna_contact', 'group_lubuvna_subscriber'];
// then return
return in_array($el['key'], $keysToImports);
```

Full code update:

```
$lubuvna_groups = acf_get_field_groups();

$ArrayDiffs = array_diff($resultsFilesKey, $resultsKey);

foreach($ArrayDiffs as $ArrayDiff) { 
   $resultsFileToImports[] = $ArrayDiff;
}


$keysToImports = ['group_lubuvna_contact', 'group_lubuvna_subscriber'];
foreach($resultsFileToImports as $resultsFileToImportsKey) { 
    $keysToImports_filtered = array_filter($lubuvna_groups, function($el) use ($keysToImports) {
        return in_array($el['key'], $keysToImports);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you add the output for `$resultsFileToImports`? It will help to better advise on building the dynamic keyname array.

Comment: this is the output of $resultsFileToImports :  `Array ( [0] => group_lubuvna_contact [1] => group_lubuvna_coupons [2] => group_lubuvna_subscriber )`